# How to play Youtube or Real Time Streaming Protocol Videos in Windows 8 Metro apps?

Tags: wpf, youtube, windows-8, youtube-api, rtsp

I am building one app which can pick videos from our channel and list and play from within the application.
I have done all the json parsing and have everything ready but the only problem
is that I am not able to play the rtsp videos coming from the Youtube API.
I have read that it is possible to play rtsp videos using the **MediaElement** control
but its not working, my sample XAML code is as below.

```
<MediaElement Width="500" Height="500" AutoPlay="True" Source="rtsp://v6.cache5.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwkNCW3rSEjLahMYDSANFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp"/>
```

I have also looked at [Player Framework for Windows 8 Metro Style Applications](http://playerframework.codeplex.com) and [Smooth Streaming Client SDK](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/04423d13-3b3e-4741-a01c-1ae29e84fea6?SRC=Home)

Using these I am able to play a direct video stored in the server(http://localhost/video.mp4), but not videos streamed via rtsp.
Please help. I want mainly youtube videos via rtsp to be played 
I have searched a lot but not finding any solution, please help.

The rtsp stream is also working I have tried playing via VLC, its playing there.

OS: Windows 8 Release Preview w/ VS 2012 Express for Windows 8

Comment: Have you tried the RTM version instead of the RP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's more to playing YouTube videos than just the RTSP protocol. Your example shows a file of type **.3gp**, which is traditionally treated as QuickTime and not playable by MediaElement. MediaElement *can*, however, play MP4s and with a codec installed and a custom DirectShow graph it's even able to play FLVs. There's even a sample WPF YouTube player discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/wpf-disciples/X6F3AXqCW10) and it looks like the source is still [available for download](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Portals/21/blog/Files/YouViewer.zip).