# Stream Youtube video in MediaElement - Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

I am programming Windows 8 Store apps (using c#/xaml).

I need to show a YouTube-video, but without using the embedded YT-player in a WebView. The reason for this is: The Youtube-Player has back links to YouTube (you can't remove them) and I don't want them.

So I thought about streaming YT-videos in an **MediaElement**, but I am not able to figure out how you could do this. I've looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330118/how-to-play-youtube-or-real-time-streaming-protocol-videos-in-windows-8-metro-ap), but I wasn't able to find a solution for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add html content to a WebView.

Add script like this>>

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelementplayer.css" />
```

Add youtube video as>>

```
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?..." />
</video>
```

OR AS>>

```
using MyToolkit.Multimedia;
var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(youtubeid, YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);
var YoutubePlayer = new MediaElement();
YoutubePlayer.Source = url.Uri;
```

Here some steps are shown that might be helpful to you>>

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/playing-video-in-metro-style-app-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: Thank you very much. Just found a post in the [MSDN board](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/faa7642f-3660-46ae-a5ed-7c19d168f1ab/) about that [MyToolkit NuGet Packet](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/). I am using this now. Very impressive workaround.  
  
Edit: Regarding your first solution (HTML in a WebView) i guess that this would serve an embedded player...

Comment: Okey, fine, I am happy that you have found solution.

Comment: mytoolkit solution does not work anymore. I was using it too, but now it takes like 10 seconds to actually get the url, and after that, the video won't play. I call mediaelement.Play() and nothing happens. No error, no nothing...